# Showing Tabcontainers Tab on the basis of user login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have made an ajax tabcontainer on main.aspx page, the tabcontainer consist of no of tabs, i want to show tabs on the basis of user login and which tabs are accessible to him need to be mention in the database.

I tried looping around the tabcontainer but  didn't get the right way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can tabs count be any number or do you have certain presets for tabs layout?

Comment: i have total 10 tabs, out of some are for HR, some for normal employees

Comment: So it means only 2 presets. I think it could be easier to wrap Tab control into UserControl and assign needed number of tabs in markup. Then load either HrTabs.ascx or EmplyeeTabs.ascx to a place where tabs are located.